# Intel PIN:Initial Set up of Intel PIN tool

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, intel, cpu-architecture

I am new to PIN tool. I just tried to run the example code given in the readme file.
Initially I build using :

```
$ cd source/tools/ManualExamples
$ make all
```

It compiled correctly and created Obj-intel64 folder with .so and .o files 
but when I compiled $ make inscount0.test
I'm getting the following message:

```
pavan@pavan-Inspiron-5521:~/Drive/PIN/pin-2.13-61206-gcc.4.4.7-linux/source/tools/ManualExamples$ make inscount0.test   
make -C ../../../source/tools/Utils dir obj-intel64/cp-pin 

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pavan/Drive/PIN/pin-2.13-61206-gcc.4.4.7-linux/source/tools/Utils'  
mkdir -p obj-intel64 
g++  -DTARGET_IA32E -DHOST_IA32E -DFUND_TC_TARGETCPU=FUND_CPU_INTEL64 -DFUND_TC_HOSTCPU=FUND_CPU_INTEL64 -DTARGET_LINUX -DFUND_TC_TARGETOS=FUND_OS_LINUX -DFUND_TC_HOSTOS=FUND_OS_LINUX  -O3   -o obj-intel64/cp-pin cp-pin.cpp    

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pavan/Drive/PIN/pin-2.13-61206-gcc.4.4.7-linux/source/tools/Utils'  

../../../pin   -t obj-intel64/inscount0.so --  ../../../source/tools/Utils/obj-intel64/cp-pin makefile obj-intel64/inscount0.makefile.copy \
      > obj-intel64/inscount0.out 2>&1 

make: *** [inscount0.test] Error 127
```

Regards,
Pavan

Comment: Have you built the pin binary itself? What happens when you just run `../../../pin -t inscount0.so -- /bin/ls` ?

Comment: I run the above command and I'm getting the following command:
pavan@pavan-Inspiron-5521:~/Drive/PIN/pin-2.13-61206-gcc.4.4.7-linux/source/tools/ManualExamples$ ../../../pin -t obj-intel64/inscount0.so -- /bin/ls
bash: ../../../pin: No such file or directory

Comment: Then you probably didn't build pin, or you're in the wrong dir

Comment: I Just downloaded pin-2.13-61206-gcc.4.4.7-linux.tar.gz extracted it. and tried running the command given in the readme file. DO I need to run PIN binary file ./pin or ./pin.sh?.

Comment: Also the current version of GCC is 4.6.3 Will this a issue?

Answer (score 0):

To make a particular pin tool, you have to give the command as
$ make obj-intel64/**toolname**.so
If you want to run the pin tool on some target, let the path to pin binary is $PIN_ROOT and path to pin tools is $PIN_TOOL
$ $PIN_ROOT/pin -t $PIN_TOOL/**pintool_folder**/obj-intel64/**toolname**.so -- **target**